# Read specific remote line with PHP

Tags: php, twitter, remote-server

I'm trying to find a way to load my latest tweet with PHP.
At this URL, I change "Twitter.xml" to my username-".xml."
https://twitter.com/users/show/Twitter.xml

The latest tweet is shown on line 49, but I don't think PHP can read a remote file... I want it to show line 49, but how do I combine it with finding a file on a remote server?

Thanks

Comment: How would you access the remote file? http? nfs? file share? ftp?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use `file_get_contents()` to get the contents of that url. For example

`$xml = file_get_contents('https://twitter.com/users/show/Twitter.xml');`

This will only work if the config setting for `allow_url_fopen` is set to On

Answer (score 0):

Use curl to fetch a remote resource.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Then, since it's xml, I would convert it to a native PHP object, using SimpleXML

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php